# date(from string: String) always returns nil

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a NSDate on the iPhone App, that I need on the corresponding Watch App to do calculations, I don t even need to show it in a local format. Somehow it is working not really good if I transfer NSDate objects, I read that it s better to use Strings for transfer.

So I format my NSDate to a NSString. I tried different ways, and on the Watch side if I want to reverse it, I obviously use the same format. But it always returns nil and I don t understand why.

My code on the iPhone side:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];
```

I also tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:myDateObject];
```

and I tried with:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

On the Watch side I need to reverse my String to a date object:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date (from: result["dateString"] as! String)
```

and:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
ddateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
dateFormatter.locale = .current
ateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
let date = dateFormatter.date (from: result["dateString"] as! String)
```

and with

```
dateFormatter.locale = .current
```

when I mouseover

```
result["dateString"]
```

I See a date string like

```
12/17/20, 12:27 PM
```

but the date(from string: String) always returns nil.

I also tried to set the format to fit like:

```
dateformat = "MM/dd/yyyy, h:mm a"
```

but nothing works. As I said, I don t need a specific localized format, I just need day and time, a date object to calculate with. What can I do?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You don't format needs to match the input, so something more like `MM/dd/yy, HH:mm a` should work

Comment: You may also need to include `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` to ensure you don't run into issue with different locales on user devices (and, yes, I've had this happen to many times before)

Answer (score 0):

First, make your date format match your input

A input like `"12/17/20, 12:27 PM"` suggests a format of something like `MM/dd/yy, h:m a`

Next, remove any possible issues the user's current locale may introduce by using something like `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`, unless you can guarantee the locale format, this should suffice for most cases

For example

```
let dateString = "12/17/20, 12:27 PM"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, h:m a"
let date = dateFormatter.date (from: dateString)
```

will generates `2020-12-17 01:27:00 +0000` on my PC (and could change depending on your system, which is why, it's always important to use a known `DateFormatter` to debug dates - removes possible confusion)

Comment: `h:m`? I have never seen a time with a single digit for minutes. `"MM/dd/yyyy, h:mm a"` looks correct to me. OP issue is probably the device set to 24h time and setting the locale to "en_US_POSIX" should fix the issue.

Comment: @LeoDabus The test I did seemed to work (for single minutes), my guess is `mm` will produce `01` instead of `1`, but I was focused on parsing the `String` and not formatting a date value

Comment: DateFormatter is lenient when parsing but if OP use the same date formatter to create a string from date the result would be awful

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure, but for the purpose it's been used, it's fine

Answer (score 0):

A great way to serialise dates is to use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` which returns a `double` value. So on the iPhone side you'd have

```
double t = [myDateObject timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Note that formally this will return `TimeInterval` but that is just a `double` and easy to cast.

The double you can either use as is or convert to string - this depends on how you transmit it. You have e.g. `-setDouble:forKey` and `-doubleForKey` with `NSUserDefaults` where you can use it as is as a double or you can print it to string using something like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", t]
```

This produces 20 digits after the decimal separator, which is overkill but you won't loose anything at least.

Once you have read or converted the `double` on the watch side you can of simply use `NSDate`'s

```
init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval)
```

to convert the `double` back to a date.